# Cannot install Readline with Rakudo Perl 6 zef

Tags: raku, rakudo, rakudo-star, zef

I'm trying to install Readline.

(The system is Linux Mint Mate 18.3, the same is true for Lubuntu 17.10).

```
$ zef install Readline
```

The installation process begins but later is aborted with the following messages:

```
===> Searching for: Readline
===> Searching for missing dependencies: LibraryCheck
===> Testing: LibraryCheck:ver<0.0.6>:auth<github:jonathanstowe>
===> Testing [OK] for LibraryCheck:ver<0.0.6>:auth<github:jonathanstowe>
===> Testing: Readline:ver<0.0.2>:auth<github:drforr>
# Failed test 'initialize'
# at t/02-base.t line 10
# Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'macro-dumper lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 18
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Looks like you failed 1 test of 1
# Failed test 'dumpers'
# at t/02-base.t line 13
    # Failed test 'set-prompt lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 27
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'expand-prompt lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 29
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'on-new-line-with-prompt lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 31
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'save-prompt lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 33
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'restore-prompt lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 35
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Looks like you failed 5 tests of 5
# Failed test 'prompt'
# at t/02-base.t line 24
    # Failed test 'tilde-expand lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 46
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'tilde-expand-word lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 48
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Looks like you failed 2 tests of 2
# Failed test 'tilde'
# at t/02-base.t line 39
    # Failed test 'prep-terminal lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 58
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'deprep-terminal lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 60
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'reset-terminal'
    # at t/02-base.t line 62
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Looks like you failed 3 tests of 3
# Failed test 'terminal'
# at t/02-base.t line 54
    # Failed test 'reset-line-state lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 70
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Looks like you failed 1 test of 1
# Failed test 'state'
# at t/02-base.t line 68
    # Failed test 'free-undo-list lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 81
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'do-undo lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 83
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'begin-undo-group lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 85
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'end-undo-group lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 87
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Looks like you failed 4 tests of 4
# Failed test 'undo'
# at t/02-base.t line 80
    # Failed test 'funmap-names lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 99
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Looks like you failed 1 test of 1
# Failed test 'funmap'
# at t/02-base.t line 91
    # Failed test 'set-screen-size'
    # at t/02-base.t line 106
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'reset-screen-size lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 110
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Looks like you failed 2 tests of 2
# Failed test 'screen'
# at t/02-base.t line 103
    # Failed test 'insert-text lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 118
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'delete-text lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 120
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'kill-text lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 122
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'copy-text lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 124
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Looks like you failed 4 tests of 4
# Failed test 'text'
# at t/02-base.t line 114
    # Failed test 'make-bare-keymap lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 132
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'copy-keymap lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 134
    # Type check failed in binding to parameter '$map'; expected Readline::Keymap but got Any (Any)
    # Failed test 'make-keymap lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 136
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'discard-keymap lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 138
    # Type check failed in binding to parameter '$map'; expected Readline::Keymap but got Any (Any)
    # Failed test 'get-keymap-by-name lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 145
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'get-keymap lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 147
    # Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    # Failed test 'get-keymap-name lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 149
    # Type check failed in binding to parameter '$map'; expected Readline::Keymap but got Any (Any)
    # Failed test 'set-keymap lives'
    # at t/02-base.t line 151
    # Type check failed in binding to parameter '$map'; expected Readline::Keymap but got Any (Any)
    # Looks like you failed 8 tests of 8
# Failed test 'keymap'
# at t/02-base.t line 128
Cannot locate native library 'libreadline.so': libreadline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  in method setup at /opt/rakudo-pkg/share/perl6/sources/24DD121B5B4774C04A7084827BFAD92199756E03 (NativeCall) line 289
  in method CALL-ME at /opt/rakudo-pkg/share/perl6/sources/24DD121B5B4774C04A7084827BFAD92199756E03 (NativeCall) line 576
  in method make-bare-keymap at /home/evb/.zef/store/perl6-readline.git/e2cf431a87c36d420a3f2737b2cbc160efeb9233/lib/Readline.pm (Readline) line 1040
  in sub  at t/02-base.t line 162
  in sub subtest at /opt/rakudo-pkg/share/perl6/sources/C712FE6969F786C9380D643DF17E85D06868219E (Test) line 411
  in sub  at t/02-base.t line 161
  in sub subtest at /opt/rakudo-pkg/share/perl6/sources/C712FE6969F786C9380D643DF17E85D06868219E (Test) line 411
  in block <unit> at t/02-base.t line 155

===> Testing [FAIL]: Readline:ver<0.0.2>:auth<github:drforr>
Aborting due to test failure: Readline:ver<0.0.2>:auth<github:drforr> (use --force-test to override)
  in code  at /home/evb/.perl6/sources/0061125F96D1E60B6E3B0001A4CB4D4188DF4869 (Zef::Client) line 375
  in method test at /home/evb/.perl6/sources/0061125F96D1E60B6E3B0001A4CB4D4188DF4869 (Zef::Client) line 353
  in code  at /home/evb/.perl6/sources/0061125F96D1E60B6E3B0001A4CB4D4188DF4869 (Zef::Client) line 530
  in sub  at /home/evb/.perl6/sources/0061125F96D1E60B6E3B0001A4CB4D4188DF4869 (Zef::Client) line 527
  in method install at /home/evb/.perl6/sources/0061125F96D1E60B6E3B0001A4CB4D4188DF4869 (Zef::Client) line 633
  in sub MAIN at /home/evb/.perl6/sources/C360CEB3AF792C33F65155FA82FDB7AB4467EC82 (Zef::CLI) line 152
  in block <unit> at bin/zef line 3
```

`locate libreadline.so` gives the following output:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.5
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.5.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.3
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `locate libreadline.so`? Do you have "/usr/lib/libreadline.so" and "libreadline.so.VERSION"? Can you add these answers to your question? We need to figure out why Readline is failing to open libreadline.so.

Comment: @piojo Thanks. I've added the output to the Q. I've tried to install Readline on another system (lubuntu) with the same result.

Comment: Try installing libreadline-dev - "sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev"

Comment: @CurtTilmes Success! Thank you very much!! I wonder, whether you could make it an Answer?

Comment: The problem is not that a packages is missing (centainly not a -dev one), but that p6-Readline does not refer to a specific lib version and the code that looks for the lib does not find any lib. Adding 'v7' to tib loading code works without adding addtional packages. See my answer about the patched p6-Readline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many distributions, including debian/ubuntu and friends encourage a certain separation between packaging, more information in the [debian.org packaging docs](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/advanced.en.html).

In particular, they encourage distribution of shared libraries for certain versions (such as `.so.1`) that are dependencies of other packages separate from the 'unversioned' `.so` that are more typically used for 'development' (in distribution packages ending in `-dev`).

From the above docs:

> Please note that the development package should contain a symlink for the associated shared library without a version number. E.g.: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfoo.so -> libfoo.so.1`

For readline, that link is in the `libreadline-dev` package, which can be installed on mint/ubuntu/debian type systems like this: `sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev`

Perl 6 [NativeCall](https://docs.perl6.org/language/nativecall#Library_Paths_and_Names) docs discuss this too:

> If you write native('foo') NativeCall will search libfoo.so under Unix
>   like system (libfoo.dynlib on OS X, foo.dll on win32). In most modern
>   system it will require you or the user of your module to install the
>   development package because it's recommended to always provide an
>   API/ABI version to a shared library, so libfoo.so ends often being a
>   symbolic link provided only by a development package.
>
> To avoid that, the native trait allows you to specify the API/ABI
>   version. It can be a full version or just a part of it. (Try to stick
>   to Major version, some BSD code does not care for Minor.)

It looks like Readline [does not specify a specific API/ABI version](https://github.com/drforr/perl6-readline/blob/master/lib/Readline.pm#L657). (perhaps it should?)

Since it does not, it will look for the unversioned shared library (plain `.so`).

Comment: I do this wrong in some of my own modules -- I'm going to add the API/ABI version to them when I get a chance.

Comment: Looks like the version was originally present for readline, but was removed as part of the libreadline v6 -> v7 migration: https://github.com/drforr/perl6-readline/issues/12

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the explanations! I already use Readline, which seems much more convenient than Linenoise.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky: can you expand on why? I am thinking of adding it to rakudo containers.

Comment: @nxadm Not sure that I remember the details but when I made an interactive program using line editing, I remember that Readline was much more convenient than Linenoise.

Comment: @nxadm I know, what was bad! Linenoise treats non-ASCII characters terribly, so I was (and am) extremely happy when I migrated to Readline.

Answer (score 3):

See [this perl6-readline issue](https://github.com/drforr/perl6-readline/issues/22).

Until @drforr has time to sort out the versions, I created a temporarely fork that installs fine on Ubuntu 18.04 and all the distributions using libreadline version 7.

To install the module:

```
$ zef install https://github.com/nxadm/perl6-readline.git
```

If you want to patch the issue yourself (1 line patch), you can follow the instructions in [my comment on a related issue](https://github.com/drforr/perl6-readline/issues/12#issuecomment-388162449).